# How which custom android OS stock rom version (7-12) virtually pre load/check/test have adoptable storage format sd card as internal storage option

Tags: internal-storage, custom-roms, app2sd, adoptable-storage

question which  custom android OS stock rom version (6,7.1,8.1,9.1.10,11,12.1) and how to virtually (VM) pre load pre check test have adoptable storage format sd card as internal storage option

the  mobile device i want to  load custom rom is lyf water 7  as it have android 5.1.1 lolipop but it dont have option to  move app to sd card either its locked ot not suitable or compatible for rom device but same company other models with android 5.1.1 have option to  move app to sd card following custom roms  is available for the same device i want to  know which  android version will have  format  external sd as internalal or move aap to  sd option enable for my device

https://www.getdroidtips.com/custom-rom-lyf-water-7/

1. Android 10 Q stable
2. Android 9 Pie.
3. Android 8.1 OREO
4. Android 7.1 Nougat
5. Android 11
6. android 12.1 CyanogenMod

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/cm_12-1-stable-ls-5504-_lyf_water-7.3595710/

I had shared the link of the modified  custom roms not from manufacturer vendor but from xda or 3rd party sites don't know it authentic safe or chances to brick the mobile...how can I pre check  pre test the custom rom  before installing either it have adoptable storage (formatting micro sd card as internal)  through pre loading running testing checking custom rom  virtually in som virtual machine (VM) type apps so that phone device don't get hardware or software bricked too.

i want to  root and install custom rom on my mobile and want to purchase new android mobile ( samsung m21 m31) i  am searching that which android supports  formatting  external sd card as internal and have  option to move apps to sd card  or auto install apps to sd card kindly suggest the  android OS version compatible for  adaptable storage

Comment: It is supported from 6.0 to current version 11. You are well advised to read the [tag  wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) of the tag you used and decide next steps // Given 128 GB is pretty standard these days, also think hard - do you really need to go this path?

Comment: Note that some manufacturer remove or disable adoptable storage in their devices. BTW: there is no "Android 12.1 CyanogenMod", the CyanogenMod project is dead for years. The last CyanogenMod version was 14.1 which corresponds to Android 7. Furthermore Android 12.1 is not yet released. Based on rumors we expect it to come 2022.

Comment: adoptable-storage does not require root at all, either it works out of the box, or root solutions are your only alternative, there is "no" way to make adoptable-storage storage work with root

Comment: @Robert bro  android 12.1 CyanogenMod  for my mobile device I found link on xda either it's modified don't know it's aithenticiry or genuiity ..kindly check and tell is it safe to use this customised rom or not

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/cm_12-1-stable-ls-5504-_lyf_water-7.3595710/

Comment: @Androidquery Nobody can tell you if a customROM you found on the net is safe or not. Even if the source code would be completely available it would take weeks as a full-time job to verify if a ROM is safe. Therefore you can only check who has developed a ROM and if you trust this person.

Comment: try this ROM [XenonHD](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3693500) Android 7.1.1 or [CyanogenMod13](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3694289) Android 6.0.1 or ask Gautam Maini in [Telegram](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/volte-7-1-1-xenonhd-nougat-for-lyf-water-7.3693500/page-7#post-79859800) group for LineageOS [16.0-20191229-UNOFFICIAL-zx55q05](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachments/screenshot_20191231-182441_settings-png.4915017) Android 9.0

Comment: @Androidquery just to be clear, the XDA post you linked is CyanogenMod 12.1 based on *Android 5.1*, not Android 12.1 (Android 12 hasn't even been released yet for public usage at this moment). The CyanogenMod (and its successor, Lineage OS) version is always 7 higher than the Android version that is based on.

Comment: @Robert bro as you said "Note that some manufacturer remove or disable adoptable storage in their devices." How to test or  check device is enable or  disabled  the adobtable storage in ROM device hardware any adb shell command or any configration or any bechmarking hardware info  apps kindly suggest or tell the way to test for hardware mobil device compatibilty

Comment: it's easy to figure out if you got hands on one phone, but it's hard to answer if you don't have any concrete device model in mind

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's hard to answer because it depends on encryption type and vendor. For example adoptable-storage is not compatible with Android 7.0 - 8.1 with (FBE) file-based encryption. Some devices support adoptable-storage but GUI lacks functionality - intentionally on vendors decision. Some of that limitations can bypassed from cmd line, but you might end up with successfully adopted storage and unmoveable apps

Comment: bro I have edited 300-400 and made some apps movable through apk editor app in one of my mobile with android 7.0 and then extracted the apps and save the installers through apk extractor app and apps installing and made them movable  secondly when downloaded and installed from apkpure it's auto installs by default in adpatable storage that is the  external micro sd card formatted as  internal storage in android 6 phone so I want to check test it in android 7,8,9,10,11,12  by loading customized rom available for my handset

Comment: bro yes i know it depends on hardware mobile manufacturer compatibility issues to...but major part depends on OS encryption method or files system security and many other things...but when the rom is modified customised programmed or tailored by 3rd party tailor made developer then as android is open source they must programm and remove the limitations is there any way to pretest prechek the custom rom by loading in any virtual machine app on Android phone to check if that cuatomised rom will work fine or not. And it's having adoptable storage compatibility or not

Comment: bro I have detailed that inam using Lyf water 7 ls-5015 for customised rom and planning to purcase samsung m21 or m31  so kindly suggest me which  android os version and mobile is GUI and FBE is compatible for andaptable storage and how can we pre check or pretest android OS  through vitrually loading  whether the is compatible with mobile device and have features compatibility or not

Comment: Lyf water Android 5.1.1 Lollipop is not compatible https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable Samsung does not support adoptable-storage https://www.samsung.com/sg/support/mobile-devices/does-galaxy-s9-or-s9-plus-2018-support-the-adoptable-storage-feature

Comment: Lyf water 7 has inbuilt android 5.1.1  lolipop does not  support adaptable buas it's lolipop os by default if we upgrade or update or install custom rom android 6 then will it support or not. As Lyf water 7  used to have same android 5.1.1 lolipop but company manufacturer vendor itself gave an upgraded  update for it for android 6.0 mashemellow all if a sudden  and it got the adaptable storage option . But manufacturer vender don't have update os upgrade for water 7 as not much sold device  so if I upgrade from xda or 3rd party devloper then can I get such option for device